# How to use my local computer camera in android emulator?

Tags: android

How to use my local computer camera in android emulator?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment it's not possible in the emulator itself, but Tom Gibara has written a small component to do it anway, check his article "[Live Camera Previews in Android](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source)" about the temporary solution.

A [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36905920) is already made for this functionality to be added to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use your computer webcam to use as android emulator camera.You just need to set these options to webcam.
[image]