# Webcam for testing camera in Android AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Can I use my webcam connected to the AVD for testing camera and its functionality?

I have read in some articles that Android 3.0 + supports this feature.Is it possible?

I also receive a connect cam dialog box when my webcam is connected, when I start my AVD.

Comment: Check out this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298202/how-to-use-my-local-computer-camera-in-android-emulator][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298202/how-to-use-my-local-computer-camera-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Eclipse.

- AVD Manager
- Edit the AVD.
- Hardware > New:
- Configures camera facing backwards = "webcam0" (use dropdown).

Run project using that AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Its some tricky way either its work or not I don't know...

But you can try it, Look at [How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

[Live camera preview in the Android emulator](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/09/live-camera-preview-in-android-emulator.html)

[Live Camera Previews in Android](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source)

Comment: ya i tried but nothing is happening when i click an image with the emulator;rather the default image is shown...

Comment: Have you tried the last one link? I heard most of succeed on that way.. Try that and let me know what happen..